Sharding function for Distributed VersionedCollapsingMergeTree
The document seems to be silent on sharding function for Distributed VersionedCollapsingMergeTree or CollapsingMergeTree. Shouldn't the data written to cancel the previous row should go to the same shard for it to work ? I tried a rand function and it did not work. But using a hash function (sipHash64 on the ORDERING keys) worked. This is an important detail but I could never see it mentioned in any article. Would it not be better to document this explicitly ?
Thanks
Mohan


Shouldn't the data written to cancel the previous row should go to the same shard for it to work ?

It "should" but it doesn't have to. My bad - it "must" be on the same shard, or it won't get deduplicated...so you are correct.

I tried a rand function and it did not work.
What didn't work? Make sure you add FINAL to your queries so that duplicated rows are removed from your query result. And rand is not going to ensure that rows with the same sort order end up on the same shard, so you should use a hash function or some other logic.


But using a hash function (sipHash64 on the ORDERING keys) worked
Good choice - rows with the same key go to the same shard.

Still not sure about your definition of "worked". Keep in mind that you will have duplicate rows in a CollapsingMergeTree table, at least until parts merge. That's what FINAL is for - to remove the duplicates from your queries.

I want to clarify what I meant by "works". In my use case, I am updating rows where you use -ve value to cancel the previous row followed by -ve sign with an increased version number and some columns updated. If you do this with VersionedCollapsingMergeTree (non-replicated) it will result in 1 row - the latest rows that was added. This happens almost immediately, did not wait for merge and don't event need FINAL. Same behavior can be obtained for the Distributed version (tested on a 3 node cluster) with hash function i.e., without waiting to merge or FINAL.

Sorry about my initial answer - I read it today and thought "what was I thinking?" I fixed it. You need a proper sharding key in your Distributed table.  On a separate note: you need FINAL in your queries. CollapsingMergeTree (with or without a version) does not delete rows immediately. Your queries should assume there are duplicates.

Agreed. I understand that merge is a complex process. Merge is happening quickly for some updates and for some others it is slow.
